# What do we do about the Coq tag wrt the rename to Rocq?

Tags: discussion

Since the language Coq has been renamed to Rocq, should we also rename or redirect the tag?

Comment: I don't think we need to be too eager about that before their home page changes name. Meanwhile a tag wiki mention is reasonable.